# Is there a way to fetch all the rows which is looped inside cursor in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am a newbie in coding. I would like to know if there's a way to select all the items in `MY_CURSOR` ?

Here is what I did:

```
DECLARE @contractTypeFinalDependent1 VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @contractTypeFinal1 VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY FOR 
    SELECT * 
    FROM @sampleTable

OPEN MY_CURSOR

FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @contractTypeFinalDependent1, @contractTypeFinal1

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @contractTypeFinalDependent1, @contractTypeFinal1
END

CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR

SELECT * FROM MY_CURSOR
```

Comment: In SQL Server, you don't need a cursor at all to select all items. Just execute `SELECT * FROM @sampleTable;`.

Comment: Thankyou sir, I already got it.